# Change second tabset on click in flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm working on a self-contained flexdashboard project and I'm wondering if it's possible when a user clicks to a new tab in one tabset, it changes to a new tab on a second tabset as well.

So for example, when you click on "Chart B1" below, I would also like to change view to "Chart B2" in the second column. And clicking on "Chart A2" would change back to "Chart A1", etc. etc.

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A1

### Chart B1

Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A2

### Chart B2
````

Note, this was [first posted on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/change-second-tabset-on-click-in-flexdashboard), but did not receive any responses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be implemented with JavaScript. Luckily, Knitr supports embedded Javascript. I am an R programmer foremost, so this may not necessarily be the most concise implementation, but it does achieve the correct effect.

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```

    Column {.tabset}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Chart A1
    Chart A1 is Great

    ### Chart B1
    Chart B1 is Great

    Column {.tabset}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Chart A2
    Chart A2 is Great

    ### Chart B2
    Chart B2 is Great

    ```{js}
    // Once the Document Has Fully Loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      // Select The Tabs
      window.a1Tab = document.querySelector("#column > ul > li:nth-child(1)");
      window.b1Tab = document.querySelector("#column > ul > li:nth-child(2)");
      window.a2Tab = document.querySelector("#column-1 > ul > li:nth-child(1)");
      window.b2Tab = document.querySelector("#column-1 > ul > li:nth-child(2)");

      // Select the Panel Content
      window.a1Panel = document.getElementById('chart-a1');
      window.b1Panel = document.getElementById('chart-b1');
      window.a2Panel = document.getElementById('chart-a2');
      window.b2Panel = document.getElementById('chart-b2');

      // If We Click on B1, Open B2, Close A2
      b1Tab.addEventListener('click', function(){
        a2Tab.classList.remove('active');
        a2Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        a2Panel.classList.remove('active');

        b2Tab.classList.add('active');
        b2Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        b2Panel.classList.add('active');
      }, false);

      // If We Click on B2, Open B1, Close A1
      b2Tab.addEventListener('click', function(){
        a1Tab.classList.remove('active');
        a1Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        a1Panel.classList.remove('active');

        b1Tab.classList.add('active');
        b1Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        b1Panel.classList.add('active');
      }, false);

      // If We Click on A1, Open A2, Close B2
      a1Tab.addEventListener('click', function(){
        b2Tab.classList.remove('active');
        b2Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        b2Panel.classList.remove('active');

        a2Tab.classList.add('active');
        a2Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        a2Panel.classList.add('active');
      }, false);

      // If We Click on A2, Open A1, Close B1
      a2Tab.addEventListener('click', function(){
        b1Tab.classList.remove('active');
        b1Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        b1Panel.classList.remove('active');

        a1Tab.classList.add('active');
        a1Tab.children[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        a1Panel.classList.add('active');
      }, false);
    });

    ```
````

Edit: For an unlimited number of tabs, assuming that you will always have the same number of tabs in the first and second column. Same disclaimer, this is not necessarily the most concise implementation, but achieves the desired effect.

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```

    Column {.tabset}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Chart A1
    Chart A1 is Great

    ### Chart B1
    Chart B1 is Great

    ### Chart C1
    Chart C1 is Great

    ### Chart D1
    Chart D1 is Great

    Column {.tabset}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Chart A2
    Chart A2 is Great

    ### Chart B2
    Chart B2 is Great

    ### Chart C2
    Chart C2 is Great

    ### Chart D2
    Chart D2 is Great

    ```{js}
    // Once the Document Has Fully Loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      // Select The Tabs
      window.col1Tabs = document.querySelector("#column > ul");
      window.col2Tabs = document.querySelector("#column-1 > ul");

      // Select the Panel Content
      window.col1Panels = document.querySelector("#column > div");
      window.col2Panels = document.querySelector("#column-1 > div");

      // Function to Make Tabs Active
      window.handleTab = function(tabIndex){
        for(i=0;i<col1Tabs.childElementCount;i++){
          col1Tabs.children[i].classList.remove('active');
          col2Tabs.children[i].classList.remove('active');
          col1Panels.children[i].classList.remove('active');
          col2Panels.children[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
        col1Tabs.children[tabIndex].classList.add('active');
        col2Tabs.children[tabIndex].classList.add('active');
        col1Panels.children[tabIndex].classList.add('active');
        col2Panels.children[tabIndex].classList.add('active');
      }

      // For All Tabs, Add Event Listener
      for(i=0;i<col1Tabs.childElementCount;i++){
        col1Tabs.children[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'handleTab(' + i + ');');
        col2Tabs.children[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'handleTab(' + i + ');');
      }

    });

    ```
````

Edit: For anyone who may find this question later, a JQuery implementation with more flexibility was added to the [Github Issue.](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/264#issuecomment-624304902)

Comment: This is great, thanks! In my real example, I have many more tabs so I'm wondering if there is some way in to specify which tabs should be "linked" to each other and have the click events generate automatically? I don't know any JS, so I don't really know where to start, but this is really useful.

Comment: Thanks for adding the update! My real life example has a different number of tabs in each column, so this won't work exactly, but you've given me more than enough to work with. And also, now I'm going to learn some JavaScript!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another answer using JQuery and boostrap tabset JS function. 
It is more concise than other answer but works the same with any number of tabs (but the same number) in your two column format.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

```{js}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e){
      // find the tab index that is click
      child = e.target.parentNode;
      tabnum = Array.from(child.parentNode.children).indexOf(child);
      // find in which column we are
      column = $(e.target).closest("div[id]");
      // show the same tab in the other column
      columnid = column.attr("id");
      if (columnid == "column") {
        columnto = "column-1";
      } else {
        columnto = "column";
      }
      $("div[id="+columnto+"] li:eq("+tabnum+") a").tab('show');
    })
});
```

Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A1

This is a text

### Chart B1

```{r}
plot(iris)
```


Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A2

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```

### Chart B2

This is another text
````

Comment: This is also great, thank you so much! I wonder if there would be an approach that works when there are a different number of tabs in each column and we could specify which tabs should be "linked" to each other in the columns. If there were 3 tabs in Col 1 and 2 tabs in Col 2, something like a1 = a2, b1 = b2, c1 = a2

Comment: Yes I guess you could create in JS an array of index by column and select from it the linked tab. like you would do in R `linkedIndex[targetIndex, columnid]`.
There could be a solution too I think where the information about the linked tab is added in a data attribute in some tabs node and you get back this information in JS